# How to check if two fields are equal in Angular / Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am wanting to check if the values of two fields are the same, these fields must be passed by parameters to the validation function, I am doing this, the problem is that it can not get the value of the field, it appears null, as Can I get the values correctly and dynamically?

My form builder, I'm using the match function to check the cell_phone and confirmation fields.

```
this.recharge = this.formBuilder.group({
  cell_phone: ['', Validators.required, Validations.match('cell_phone', 'cell_phone_confirmation')],
  cell_phone_confirmation: ['', [Validators.required]],
  value: ['', Validators.required],
  operator_id: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

In my function, console log is null:

```
static match(field1: string, field2: string){
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
    console.log(group.get(field1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a custom formGroup validator to check the value of the form controls values and check theme

```
this.recharge = formBuilder.group({
  cell_phone: ['', Validators.required],
  cell_phone_confirmation: ['', Validators.required],
},
  {
    validator: checkMatchValidator('cell_phone', 'cell_phone_confirmation')
  }
);
```

Custom Validator function

```
export function checkMatchValidator(field1: string, field2: string) {
  return function (frm) {
    let field1Value = frm.get(field1).value;
    let field2Value = frm.get(field2).value;

    if (field1Value !== '' && field1Value !== field2Value) {
      return { 'notMatch': `value ${field1Value} is not equal to ${field2}` }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53746285)

Comment: I need to pass to the function the fields that should be checked, since I also have password confirmation fields, emails and the function needs to be reusable.

Comment: what do you want to check cell and confirm tow fileld  ??

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: I have 2 password fields and password confirmation and email and email confirmation, both do the same thing as cell_confirmation, I did not want to create 3 match functions for each of these fields.

Comment: check I have create a function builder so you can use the same function to validate two fields

Comment: If you are doing it inside of Ionic, you can reference like `validator: this.checkMatchValidator('CardNumber', 'CardNumberConfirm')` and just remove the `export function` part of the function.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use root property to access to `cell_phone_validator` control

```
cell_phone: ['', [Validators.required, this.cellPhoneValidator]]


private cellPhoneValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (control.root.get('cell_phone_confirmation') {
    return control.root.get('cell_phone_confirmation').value !== control.value ?
      { cellPhoneValidator: { value: control.value } } : null;
  }
```

}

**EDIT :** you want to use it for any field, so let's make it general

```
cell_phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validations.matchValidator('cell_phone_confirmation')]],
cell_phone_confirmation: ['', [Validators.required, Validations.matchValidator('cell_phone')]]

private matchValidator(controlValidationName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const controlValidation = control.root.get(controlValidationName);
    if (!controlValidation) {
      return null;
    }
    return controlValidation.value !== control.value ?
      { matchValidator: { value: control.value } } : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse this function in another form with other fields, not exclusively for mobile, is it possible?

Comment: If you want to reuse this function, we should change it a bit

Comment: I already have a validation class where I created my custom functions.

Comment: @viniciussvl glad to help! malbarm has proposed another solution by passing validators in `legacyOrOpts` formbuilder's property. Feel free to use the one you like the most ;)

Comment: I'm glad there are several ways to solve this problem, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this.

```
this.recharge = this.formBuilder.group({
  cell_phone: ['', Validators.required],
  cell_phone_confirmation: ['', [Validators.required]],
  value: ['', Validators.required],
  operator_id: ['', Validators.required]
},{ validator:  Validations.match });

static match(c: AbstractControl){
  const cellphone = c.get('cell_phone');
  const cellphoneconfirm = c.get('cell_phone_confirmation');
}
```

Comment: In formBuilder it gave an error saying "Argument of type 'cell_phone' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'"

Comment: I need to specify which fields should be validated, as I have password, email, and cell fields.

Comment: We are passing the whole form group instance, you can access the specific form controls.