# Angular async validators added inline with ReactiveForms are triggered on new

Tags: angular

I have a custom control/component which I hook an async validator to in the ReactiveForms style e.g.

```
this.myform = new FormGroup({
  mycontrol : new FormControl('', [], this.myvalidator.bind(this)),
```

If I break on the myvalidator function, I can see that it's called multiple times, the main times being on "new FormControl" and then again when the control is assigned a value.

By hard coding the response from the validation to something like:

```
return of({ error: 'done broke...'});
```

The control receives the error in its "errors" object and the UI shows the "ng-invalid" class. All good..

I actually need my validator to know what control we're validating, in order to get the correct response from the service.  To do this I have some method named "getControlName(control)" which uses the control.parent to find the name of the current control (clunky but works for now).

Problem is! on instantiation of FormControl where we pass in the validator, that actually seems to trigger the myvalidator function, at which point the control.parent is undefined.  So I simply add a check for control.parent and return of(null) when there isn't one... except that this doesn't work.

If the validator function looks like this:

```
testVal(control: AbstractControl): Observable<{}> {
  if (!control.parent) { 
    return of(null); 
  } else {
    return of({ error: 'there is a parent this time' });
  }
```

Then I get an error on the errors object of my control and the ng-invalid is set on the class list.  Great!

But if my method looks more like this:

```
  testVal(control: AbstractControl): Observable<{}> {
  if (!control.parent) { return of(null); }

    const field = this.getControlName(control);
    const r = this.myservice.validate(field).
... service stuff ...
    return r; // this is the Observable from my service method
```

}

Then I get an error on my errors object, but the ng-valid class is still there!

Why the difference, and what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you `bind(this)` ?!

Comment: Your custom validator function should return : `null` (if the control is valid) or an object such as `{ validatorProperty: { value: control.value } }` (if the control is invalid)

Comment: @Florian I believe I can use bind(this) and then get access to functions in my component, or alternatively pass in the validator function (e.g. new FormControl('', [], this.myvalidator) ... ), and then define myvalidator as an arrow function.  Either way I get the same thing

Comment: @Florian the issue here is that 1) the control has no parent on the first time it's called, so i have to return something, 2) when i return null (valid) when there's no parent, and then an error when there is a parent (as a test) then this works!  but as soon as the validator goes off to the service it half validates it.  It adds an error to errors but leaves ng-valid in place.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand properly... Could you create a stackblitz and I try to figure out what you mean ?

Comment: this looks like junk, but shows it working correctly. Where i've put the console.log in the else is where i would make a service call.  and it behaves differently if the async validator calls a service:

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ewdim

Comment: hmm something else is going on here... i've removed the validator from the FormControl constructor and set it like this:

this.theForm.controls['mycontrol'].setAsyncValidators(this.validator);

and now i do get an "errors" on the control but the ng-valid remains.. this happens whether i return from my service or hard code to return of({error : 'test'});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53375739/228665 seems to give me a workaround!  passing in the control name rather than trying to derive it from the control.  Not as neat, but no longer get weird behaviour

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like you try to access to a another control of the form ? If so, this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746285/how-to-check-if-two-fields-are-equal-in-angular-ionic/53746536#53746536